# Error invoking "pig" in cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.8.0

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera-cdh

I am a month new to Hadoop environment, I have `cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.8.0` on my windows laptop, while invoking '`pig`' in cloudera vm, I could not able to enter into grunt shell, the error I am getting is below

> [Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file. 2017-04-25 06:39:53,207
>   [main] FATAL org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - error parsing conf
>   hdfs-default.xml org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.

Kindly let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: `error parsing conf hdfs-default.xml`, You have a malformed `hdfs-default.xml` file.

Comment: What does it mean by malformed hdfs-default.xml, did I do anything wrong while invoking 'pig', Does cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.8.0 have 'pig' or do we have to install/setup 'pig' separately.

Comment: Just to add more info. I have executed " sudo yum install pig " command on Hadoop command line interface. At present I can able to work in pig environment (grunt shell). I don't know whether above install solved my problem.

Comment: Pig is available as part of quickstart. The error msg indicated that the file called `hdfs-default.xml` is malformed. Did you edit any file of such name?

Comment: I haven't edited hdfs-default.xml, don't know why I faced the problem initially, if pig available already. Thanks